# Having trouble creating extension method on iText7's AbstractElement

Tags: c#, itext7

I want to create an extension method that will apply to both Paragraph objects as well as Text objects.  Both of these types share a common ancestor, AbstractElement.

I would like to do is something like this:

```
private static AbstractElement ApplyHeaderStyle(this AbstractElement element)
    {
        return element.AddStyle(new Style().SetFont(FontFactory.CreateAvenir85Heavy()).SetFontSize(7));
    }
```

So that I can call it in my code like this:

```
new Text("This is some text that I would like as a header").ApplyHeaderStyle();
```

or

```
new Paragraph().Add("This is also text I want in that style").AddHeaderStyle();
```

How do I do this?  Should I avoid trying to do this as a chainable extension method?

Comment: What is the problem with your code above?

Comment: This code, as written, has a compilation error "CS0305 Using the generic type 'AbstractElement<T>' requires 1 type arguments".  When I try it with T - as in "private static AbstractElement<T> HeaderStyle(this AbstractElement<T> element)", I get a different error, "CS0246 The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference)?".

Comment: I thought I was close when I tried "private static IElement HeaderStyle(this AbstractElement<IElement> element)" as the compiler no longer complains about the function, but there is another error from where I try to use this method: "new Text(headerText).HeaderStyle();". That error is "CS1929 'Text' does not contain a definition for 'HeaderStyle' and the best extension method overload '...' requires a receiver of type AbstractElement<IElement>'.

Comment: *grin* I was just starting to look into this.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out through a little trial and error a lot of googling:

```
private static T HeaderStyle<T>(this T element) where T : AbstractElement<T>
{
    return element.AddStyle(CreateHeaderStyle());
}
```